# osmdroid workaround for the classic markers overlapping

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I am developing an Android offline mapping application using osmdroid and osm bonus pack and loading the tiles and data from external storage. Right now, as the data grows, markers are starting to get cramped together, I even have the situation of two places on the same building. I know this kind of issue has been asked a lot before, mine is about a simple temporal workaround I'm thinking of implementing. How about if two places are near enough(right in top of each other!) the standard info window pops up as a ListView with each row designed like the standard bubble(image, title, moreInfoButton).

My question is: some thoughts or advices on how to create the new bonuspack_bubble.xml layout file.

Comment: Generally pin clustering should be used. I do not know if there are libraries for osmdroid, but for google maps v2 there surely are some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you.
I needed to create a `CustomInfoBubble` for my project. What I did was, to extend the `InfoWindow` default class, and pass to it my custom bubble layout. Something like this:
http://mobiledevstories.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/osmdroid-bonus-pack-markers-with-clickable-infowindows/

My Java class `MapCustomInfoBubble` looks like this:

```
public class MapCustomInfoBubble extends InfoWindow {

    public MapCustomInfoBubble(MapView mapView) {
        super(R.layout.map_infobubble_black, mapView);//my custom layout and my mapView
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose() {
      //by default, do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Object item) {
        Marker marker = (Marker)item; //the marker on which you click to open the bubble    

        String title = marker.getTitle();
        if (title == null)
                title = "";

        Button moreInfo = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_moreinfo);//the button that I have in my XML; 
        moreInfo.setText(title);
        moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             gotoMoreInfoWindow();//custom method; starts another activity
            }
        });
    }

}
```

In my XML file, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/map_infobubble_black" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/bubble_title" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
                android:maxEms="17"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Title" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/bubble_moreinfo" 
                android:background="@drawable/map_btn_moreinfo"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Somewhere else in my code, I then use:

```
Marker wp = new Marker(mapView);
wp.setPosition(new GeoPoint(mylocation.getMyLocation()));
wp.setTitle(editTextName.getText().toString());
wp.setInfoWindow(new MapCustomInfoBubble(mapView));
mapView.getOverlays().add(wp);
mapView.invalidate();
```

In my code, I set the text on the `button` with the `Marker`'s title.
The `Marker` is the item on which I click. If you want to put info about more markers in the same `InfoWindow` (inside a `ListView`), I think you would need to know in advance what the info will be.

I believe that, You can put whatever code you want inside `onOpen()`, however, I am not so sure if it's a good practice. You could try creating a custom `Constructor` and put your logic there. It should work. 
You need to pass the `Resource Id` (layout) and `mapView` to the super constructor, so it returns a valid `mView` object.

Comment: please correct if im wrong, but you are doing in runtime the modifications, well not the exact ones, that im talking of doing in the xml file, i mean to have a CustomInfoWindow, what i'm trying to do is instead of showing a single CustomInfoWindow, when two markers are too close, show a ListView in the CustomInfoWindow, each row representing a single CustomInfoWindow behaviour, with Image, Title, Subtitle and Button.

Comment: I am getting " The type MapCustomInfoBubble must implement the inherited abstract method InfoWindow.onOpen(ExtendedOverlayItem) " error. I am trying to create a new MapCustomInfoBubble under the same package.

Comment: This is not working. "Somewhere else in my code" where do I put it? What should be the name of the XML file written above?

Comment: "Somewhere else in my code" means, you put that piece of code in the Activity where you use it. I don't know where you create your markers.

The XML layout is called "map_infobubble_black", which is the same layout that was used as argument to the super call, inside the MapCustomInfoBubble constructor.