# osmdroid markers overlap each other, is there something like z-index?

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I have a osmdroid MapView with lots of markers that in many times overlap each other. Is there a way to bring selected marker to front with something like z-index?

Comment: hope this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747012/osmdroid-workaround-for-the-classic-markers-overlapping

Comment: I don't want to have a Bubble. Just want to bring selected marker to the front. Marker itself is dynamically generated with with data.

Comment: unfortunaltely i just know that Google Map V2 doesn't have Z indices didn't check osmdroid, but im not remember but i saw sometime about getOverlay to handle overlapping markers but i'm not sure maybe searching about overlay help you out.

Comment: Just a comment - in generic case pin clustering should be used. I do not know if there are any libs for osmdroid, but for google maps there surely are some

Comment: clustering is definitely a strategy.

Answer (score 6):

There is no z-index in osmdroid overlays, overlays are drawn from first to last => first is "behind", last is "in front". 
To push an overlay "in front", you have to change its relative position in the list of overlays.

If you are using OSMBonusPack, you could put your Markers in a FolderOverlay "myMarkersFolder". Then, to push an item "in front":

```
AbstractList<Overlay> list = myMarkersFolder.getItems();
Overlay selectedMarker = list.remove(selectedMarkerIndex);
list.add(selectedMarker); //add at the end = in front
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the z order when you create the OverlayItem List for the Marker Overlay, you can used add(0, item) for the top of the z order and add(item) for the back.